# Изменение всех индексов в таблице базы данных

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица базы данных SQlite3:

```
shop_cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
        id INT,
        name TEXT,
        price INT
        )""")
```

Когда я удаляю одну из строк в таблице, мне нужно изменить все `id` у всех строк в таблице.
Например, у меня есть такая таблица:

```
[(1, 'Фрукты', 100), (2, 'Овощи', 250), (3, 'Злаки', 150), (4, 'Сладости', 350)]
```

Я удаляю строку `'Овощи'` и хочу, чтобы у всех строк поменялось первое значение `id`, тоесть у 'Фрукты', осталась 1, у 'Злаки', поменялась 3 на 2, у 'Сладости', поменялась 4 на 3 и т.д.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Этот `id` - основополагающий элемент реляционных БД. Зачем его менять? (Это очень сомнительная практика). Т.е. какую именно задачу вы хотите этим решить? (с помощью триггера, да переменной задачу решить, вероятно, можно, но вот вряд ли нужно).

Comment: `хочу, чтобы у всех строк поменялось первое значение` Вы можете объяснить зачем? Просто если Вам это нужно, то это не ID это просто порядковый номер получается. Тогда уж проще его не хранить, а получать при запросе через `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @Namerek я не смог получить последний id строки таблицы, поэтому пришлось сделать привязку id для новой строки к длине таблицы.

Comment: Что значит, " я не смог получить последний id строки таблицы"? Код приведите, если реально этот id нужен. Эту проблему тогда решать надо, а не костыли использовать. Но опять же, а "последний id строки таблицы" (скорее, "id последней строки") вам зачем? Почитайте, что такое проблема "XY":-)

Comment: @Сергей сам задаюсь себе этим вопросом, просто не получалось работать со списком кортежей, поэтому придумал айди. Попробую их убрать.

Comment: Если вы сами не понимаете, что именно вы хотите, то вот это реально самая большая проблема:-)) Это нужно знать в первую очередь, все остальное без этого не имеет смысла (и относительно данной задачи, и относительно всей жизни:-))). Кстати, есть у меня подозрение, что ответом на ваш незаданный вопрос может оказаться `SELECT count(*) FROM shop`:-)

Comment: @Сергей я хочу миллиард евро)) ну а вообще, я знаю, просто обычно даю айди товарам, а сейчас понял, что можно и без них обойтись

Comment: Вы какой-нибудь курс по СУБД слушали?:-)  Вам id нужен, как ключ, прежде всего, для связи между таблицами. Если у вас одна табличка на все случаи жизни, то вы без него проживете прекрасно:-)

Answer (score 3):

В комментариях в целом описали что затея нелепая, тем не менее, если сильно хочется...

```
name_to_delete = 'Овощи'
cursor = db.cursor()
# Получаем id для удаляемой записи
cursor.execute("select id from shop where name=?", (name_to_delete,))
id_to_delete = cursor.fetchone()[0]
# Удаляем запись
db.execute(f'delete from shop where id=?', (id_to_delete,))
# Для всех элементов с id>удаленного уменьшаем на единицу id
db.execute(f'update shop set id=id-1 where id>?', (id_to_delete,))
```